# Process Output Info and WaitForExit not working?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cmd, process, copy

I have this problem with my vb.net application which copies files to a drive using the CMD function.

Here is the code:

Shell class:

```
Public Class Shell
Dim p As Process
Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread
Public Event TextToSend(ByVal sText As String)

Public Sub Start()
    p = New Process
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = Nothing
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

    p.Start()
    thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ReciveOutput)
    thread.IsBackground = True
    thread.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
End Sub
Public Sub SendCMD(ByVal Command As String)
    Try
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(Command)
        p.StandardInput.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Sub ReciveOutput()
    While True
        Try
            Dim output As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine
            If output <> Nothing Then
                RaiseEvent TextToSend(output)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End While
End Sub
Sub StopProcess()
    Try
        p.Kill()
        thread.Abort()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Form Class:

```
    For Each drive In drive_list
        'Then loop
        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
            Shell.SendCMD("copy /z /y C:\Users\thomas1\Downloads\File.img E:\")
            'Wait here until process has finished
        Next

    Next
```

I have been facing this issue for a while now. I need to have it output the progress eg. "13% Copied".

Comment: What is the result you do get? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Yeah, when it attempts to output the log, this happens: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: You have several errors in that code.  Instead of listing them, I will direct you to the [example in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).  Also, the OutputDataReceived event arrives on a secondary thread.  Any interaction with the UI will need to be invoked on the UI thread.